# Generate Invoice number & show amount when using PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

I am integrating PayPal in my website But I have some issues in it.

On [this page](http://www.rmmitchellconsulting.com/), if you click on the PayPal button here you will see one box.

I need two boxes to put amount and invoice number. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope Paypal will take you these information [Amount(if not set) and  Quantity] in this step, the description, name etc depends on you.

The invoice number will get generated and can be seen once the transaction is completed in your account